# Question on proof relating to premeasure and algebra of a set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given $\mu_0$ a premeasure on $\mathscr{A}$ where $\scr{A}$ is an algebra of some nonempty set $X$.
I am reading on a proof thats starts as follows

> for all $\epsilon>0$, given $A\in \scr{A}$ and $E\subset X$ then exist a sequence $\{B_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\subset \scr{A}$ such that $E\subset \bigcup B_i$ and $\sum \mu_0(B_i)\leq \mu^*(E)+\epsilon$.(Where $\mu^*$ is the induced outer measure)

I am confused on what guarantees the existence of such countable covers for any $E\subset X$ inside the algebra?

The algebra is only closed under finite union and complement. It also contains $X$ and the empty set. I don't see how this works. What if I pick the set $E\subset X\backslash \bigcup_{A_\alpha \in \scr{A}_\alpha} A_\alpha$? or I can just pick $B_i=X$ for all $i$?
Thanks for your clarity in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can take $B_i=X$ for all $i$. This shows non-emptiness of the set of countable covers. But the important thing is for whatever puposes one has in mind, the $B_i$ have to satisfy some extra conditions, which you omitted in the “…”.

Comment: now the existence follows because $\mu^*(E)$ is defined as an infimum (of a non-empty (by my previous comment) set of numbers, bounded below by $0$ (trivially)). Also, you really should phrase it better. The ‘for all $\epsilon>0$’ should come at the start of the sentence, otherwise the meaning is very easily altered (hence why we always say quantifiers first).